# Populating Columns with Formulas without erasing the headers

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have data with headers in an xlsx file, I'm using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to populate columns in the spreadsheet and so far good except that column headers get substituted by formulas when I run my code, which is this one:

```
import openpyxl
#Opening a Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
#Working with an specific sheet.
Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Data')
#Getting the max amount of rows in a given sheet.
row_count = Sheet.max_row


#GEO_CODE home_county
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['T'], 1):
    cellObj.value = '=A{0}'.format(i)

#Total_Count
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['U'], 1):
    cellObj.value = '=SUMIF($A$2:$A${1}, T{0},$D$2:$D${1})'.format(i, row_count)

wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

Which changes should I do to my code if I want to start copying formulas on the second row and not at the first one?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Adjust the row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: I want to start copying formulas on the second row and not at the first one

`Sheet['T']` returns a `tuple` of `Cell` objects.

```
>>> (<Cell Data.T1>, <Cell Data.T2>, <Cell Data.T3>,...)
```

To start from the second Row, skiping the first `Cell` object, change to:

```
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['T'][1:], 2):
```

> **Note**: A `tuple` is **0-based**, a `openpyxl.Worksheet` is **1-based**!

Therefore, you have to slice from index 1 to the end doing: `[1:]` and to get Row starting from Row 2, do `enumerate(..., 2)`.